# Large deviation bound for squared norm of the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure, large-deviation-theory

I want to pose this question as general as possible and ask for reference of what to do in similar situations. I'll incrementally add details to narrow down the problem.

---

I want to derive large deviation bound for $\| X + Y \|_2^2$, where $X$ and $Y$ are  $p$-dimensional dependent vectors; I believe in my situation it is impossible to compute the quantiles of $Z = \| X + Y \|_2^2$. Formally, I want to get something like
$$
\mathbb{P}( \| X + Y \|_2^2 > \lambda(x)) \le e^{-x},
$$
where $\lambda(x)$ is a deterministic function of $x$ and characteristics of $X$ and $Y$.

Are there any general techniques, approaches or ways of thinking in this most generic situation?

---

*Detail 1.* 
I know that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf\Sigma)$.

*Detail 2.*
I know that $\mathbb{E} \| X \|_2^2 \le \Delta$, for fixed $\Delta$.

*Detail 3.* 
I know that the magnitude of $Y$ is much higher than that of $X$, but I cannot formally deduce the above-mentioned inequality to something similar to 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\| Y \|_2^2 \ge \lambda_Y(x)) \le e^{-x}. 
$$
However, I know that $\lambda(x)$ should be large only because of $Y$ and not $X$.

Notice that if $\lambda(x)$ is allowed to be random then the choice $\lambda(x) = \lambda_Y(x) + \| X \|_2 + 2X^\top Y$ would do the job just fine.

---

I'd appreciate any ideas, suggestions and/or comments.

Comment: You need an indexed sequence of distributions to have a LDP. It seems you have some parameter $x$. Is this a large deviations scaling parameter? What is the law of large numbers for the sequence?

Comment: Can you just use that if $\|X+Y\| \geq \lambda$, then $\|Y\| \geq \lambda - \Delta$, and then use that $Y$ is normally distributed?

Comment: @snar, yes, $x$ is a scaling parameter, the larger $x$ the less the probability. I actually don't have any sequence of distributions, but I don't think it is an issue, since for example for $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ I know exactly how the concentration bounds look like. 
Now, the question in informal way is what if this $Y$ is corrupted with some other vector $X$ and I want similar concentration bound on the norm of their sum.

Comment: @PhoemueX,first, i don't know that bound for $\| X \|$ and $\mathbb{P}(\| Y \| \ge \lambda - \Delta) \le \mathbb{P}(\| X + Y \| \ge \lambda)$. I forgot to mention that $\lambda(x)$ should be non-random, otherwise it can be chosen properly, i'll edit the question shortly.

Comment: Oh, ok, you only have a bound on **the expectation** of $\|X\|^2$, not deterministically.

Comment: @PhoemeuX, exactly!

Comment: When you say that "the magnitude of $Y$ is much higher than that of $X$", is that a probabilistic (with high probability) statement, or deterministic? And what do you mean precisely? For example, if you know that $\|Y\| \geq \gamma \|X\|$ for some deterministic $\gamma >1$, then getting your claim should not be too difficult.

Comment: okay, so for $Y$ it is known that $\| Y \|_2^2 \asymp \text{Tr}(\mathbf{\Sigma})$, while $\| X \|_2^2 \asymp \varepsilon^2 p$, where $\varepsilon << 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This was too long for a comment, but is not an answer.

First, unless you have some LLN scaling for $\lambda(x)^{-1}(\|X+Y\|^2)$, large deviations theory seems to me only tangentially related through the techniques it uses. If there is a legitimate LDP here, then an obvious way to proceed is via the [contraction principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_principle_(large_deviations_theory)) using something like the transformation $T(x,y) = (x+y)^2$.

Next, as PhoemueX, points out, if you know something like $\|Y\| \geq \|X\|$ a.s., then the answer is fairly straightforward. We would have, for any $t>0$,
\begin{align*}
P(\|X+Y\|^2 \geq \lambda (x)) &= P(e^{t\|X+Y\|^2} \geq e^{t\lambda(x)}) \\
&\leq e^{-t\lambda(x)} E[e^{t(\|X\|^2+\|Y\|^2+2 X^T Y)}]\\
&= e^{-t\lambda(x)} E[e^{t(\|Y\|^2+\|Y\|^2+2 \|Y\|^2)}]\\
&= e^{-t\lambda(x)} E[e^{4t \|Y\|^2}].
\end{align*}
Since $Y$ is a mean-zero Gaussian vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, we can identify the distribution of the sum of squares. If for instance, $\Sigma = I$ is diagonal, then $\|Y\|^2$ is $\chi^2$, and you can evaluate the moment generating function to be $(1-2t)^{-p/2}$. Optimizing over $t>0$, we would get 
\begin{align*}
P(\|X+Y\|^2 \geq \lambda (x)) &\leq \inf_{t>0} e^{-t\lambda(x)-(p/2)\log(1-2(4t))},
\end{align*}
which amounts to optimizing
$$\sup_{t>0} \bigg(\lambda(x) - \frac{p}{2} \log(1-8t)\bigg).$$
The notation $\asymp$ means different things depending on the context, so you have to clarify. If you do not have the almost sure inequality written above, then you can probably use some combination of Jensen and Holder to get a crude inequality that is what you want.

Comment: $\asymp$ is $\Theta(\cdot)$, i.e. when i write $\| X \| \asymp \alpha$ it means $c_1 \alpha \le \| X \| \le c_2 \alpha$ for positive constants $c_{1, 2}$.

Comment: I got the general idea, thank you. I got something different, but it's not crucial. 
However, I don't have $\| Y \| \ge \| X \|$ a.s. but I think I'll try to make use of this approach by using $\| Y \| \ge \| X \|$ with high probability.

Comment: It's likely I got some calculations wrong. Certainly you may split up into "good" and "bad" sets $\{\|X\| \geq \|Y\|\}$ and $\{\|X\| \leq \|Y\|\}$. Given the very strong inequalities you have from you $\asymp$ relations you should be able to obtain your desired inequality.

Comment: yes, exactly! 

I'll try to post an answer, thank you for your time, +1!

Comment: I just realized that the constants in front of $\| Y \|_2^2$, in this case $4$ is too big and the approach with $\| Y \| \ge \| X \|$ is not an option.

Comment: Really? That change shouldn't matter too much. If that's the case then you need sharper estimates and have to write out what you need more explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the rate which is acceptable but with an additional factor $4$, which is in my setup a trouble.

Comment: All that has changed is the moment generating function being evaluated at $4t$ instead of $t$. It's likely you just need to look carefully. Sharpen the bound with $\gamma \|Y\| \geq \|X\|$, be more careful with estimating $X^T Y$, and so on. If that really doesn't help then I think you've hidden something important and need to make it explicit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101735/discussion-between-pointguard0-and-snar).